# Should I train my final model on the (train+validation) set before final submission?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, kaggle

I was trying to evaluate different classification models on MNIST dataset.
There are two datasets provided : `train` - 42000 images, and `test` - 28000 images.

I first divided the original training dataset (42000 images) into a (80:20 split ) of `train_set` (33600) and `test_set` (8400) .
I trained several models, from on `training set`, `cross-validated` them on the `training_set` only, and lastly evaluated the final model on the `test_set` for generalization error.

Now that my final model is ready to generate the `submission file` using the Kaggle provided `test` set, should I train my model on the whole Kaggle provided `training` set, ie `train_set + test_set` (ie the full 42000 images provided, instead of just 33600 images that I split), since Kaggle is going to evaluate my model on its own provided `test` set ?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361494/how-to-correctly-retrain-model-using-all-data-after-cross-validation-with-early

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-on-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation this too

Comment: One more that may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52274/how-to-choose-a-predictive-model-after-k-fold-cross-validation